# how can i create array of buttons

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iPhone.what i did is creating a 4 buttons individually.i need button tag values.when ever i check it in console i got 0 for 4 buttons,because i create 4 individual buttons .But i need buttons tag values like for first button, tag value 0,for second button, tag value 1.... like this how can i done this pls post some code.Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
UIButton *theButton=[[UIButton alloc]init];
theButton.tag=i;
//set their selector using add selector
[theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
//set their frame color title or image
}

-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)inButton{
int tags=inbutton.tag;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the button tag like this :

```
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button1 setTag:1];

UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button2 setTag:2];
```

Comment: You can do this because the UIButton class inherits from the UIView class.

Answer (score 0):

By default the tag of the button is zero So if you have created four individual buttons the tag for all will be zero So What you can do is 
If you have added four buttons from the xib file then set their tag as per your requirement in the xib file itself and give them same name
If you have taken the four buttons through code then set the tag through code

```
  //Alloc buttonName1
    buttonName1.tag=0;
    //Alloc buttonName1
    buttonName1.tag=1;
 //Alloc buttonName1
    buttonName1.tag=2;
 //Alloc buttonName1
    buttonName1.tag=3;
```

And for using it you have to go with pawans answer.

hAPPY cODING...